# Typo3 is not parsing <link ..> Tag to <a href="..">

Tags: parsing, typo3, typoscript

In the backend, I edited some text with an link (a href="..."). When I switch to the HTML view of the content, I can confirm, that it's correct.

After saving, it seems that Typo3 saves that link as an  tag but don't parse it back.

I tried things like (in TypoScript):

```
page.10.marks.CONTENT.select.where = colPos=1
page.10.marks.CONTENT.wrap = <div class="main_content">|</div>
page.10.marks.CONTENT.parseFunc.tags.link < lib.parseFunc.tags.link
```

or

```
page.10.marks.CONTENT.parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE
```

But nothing works...
I'm not able to find a working solution for Typo3 >6.0.
Hope someone can help me with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the static template for `css styled content` included.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

I had some wrong TS I had to remove. Now it's working.

(removed TS:
tt_content = COA
tt_content {
  10 = TEXT
  10.field = header
  10.wrap =  **|** 
  20 = TEXT
  20.field = bodytext
})